# Iterate through a HashMap without iterator

Tags: memory, hashmap, game-engine

I'm developing a videogame and I'm having some problems iterating through hashmaps because I'm using the normal iteration process:

```
Map<Integer, Symbol> symbols = new HashMap<Integer, Symbol>();
//...

for(Symbol sym : symbols.values())
    //...
```

And this is creating an iterator every time... and it is in the main loop, so is allocating a lot of memory.

How can iterate this hashmap in an efficient way that does not allocate any memory?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have benchmark-backed evidence that this specific code is a serious performance bottleneck? Beware of premature optimization!

Comment: I have realized now... what do you suggest?